# web.config not working for multipe app in cakephp 2.2.4 on IIS7.0

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, iis-7, web-config

I have two app folder in cakephp 2.2.4 one is `admin` and one is `app`.

How can i write web.config for multiple app folder? so, my site work like

```
1. http://vibrantonline.in/admin
2. http://vibrantonline.in/app
```

one for administrator use and other for front end.

currently, i using web.config is working for only admin part, how can i change `web.config` OR `htaccess`, so its work for both.

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
     <rewrite>
       <rules>
         <clear/>
         <rule name="Imported Rule 0" stopProcessing="true">
           <match url="^(img|css|files|js)(.*)$"></match>
           <action type="Rewrite" url="admin/webroot/{R:1}{R:2}" appendQueryString="false"></action>
         </rule>
         <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
           <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
           <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
             <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
             <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
           </conditions>
           <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
         </rule>
         <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
           <match url="^$" ignoreCase="false" />
           <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
         </rule>
         <rule name="Imported Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
           <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
           <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}" />
         </rule>
         <rule name="Imported Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">
           <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
           <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
             <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
             <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
           </conditions>
           <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
         </rule>
       </rules>
     </rewrite>
   </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but did you know about prefix routing? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing

Comment: I have the same problem :/